# Continuous Data handling coming from server to iOS application

Tags: ios, xcode, multithreading

I have a scenario, where my server is sending continuous(thousands and thousands of records per seconds, milliseconds or may be in minutes) data to `iOS` application once the network connection is established.

Now the question is: How to handle the records without any data loss.

1. I can create a thread which will further create concurrent queue to handle the data. But in this case as i don't know when to awake my `MainThread` to start concurrent operations.
2. If i start concurrent queues after each milliseconds: then this will be a performance issue, as there might be a case when server send the data after 1 or 2 minute.
3. Is there any listener which can tell my `MainThread` that you are going to receive data?

Comment: use timer to call webservice with interval and use aync webservice call and when data fetched update user interface in MainThread accordingly

Comment: When you say the server is **sending** data, how is it doing that?  Does it have a socket open to your app?  What listens for these incoming "records" on the iOS side?

Comment: @Phillip, yeah there is a socket connection which enables the server to send the data to iOS app, now i want some listener which can tell the app that data is coming from the server. And based on that i can create concurrent queues.